# MySQL starts run manually with datadir param, but doesn't as a service

Tags: mysql

Why does `sudo service mysql start` not start? But a manual likes `sudo mysqld --datadir=/newlocation` does?

I have moved the data to new external harddrive formated as ext4.

I updated my.cnf  with the new location, changed the ownership of the folder, removed apparmor as I though it was responsible for not letting me start mysql. I also tried the my.cnf with user=root with no luck.

The error trying to start the service is related to "can not create test db" "Error 13 permission denied" On th eerror log the permisson denied is on the same /newlocation that works with the manual start.

I want to run the service automatically. The manual start works OK

Any ideas?

HPcolos

Answer (score 0):

You have changed permission but we dont know what permission you have set.

In Linux every services have to own username , as  you are doing it different I think you have think in that different way.

allow user of mysqld service to access your external harddrive location where you have installed  mysql.

like

chown -R mysql:mysql  /location/path

I am away from my PC, Please try this and let me know if issue still persists and by the way mention the way you have installed mysql.

Comment: I changed the permission of the new folder to match the original location (/var/lib/mysql) using the command sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /newlocation  I also used chmod command.  None of these made any difference.  Manual start works fine but using the service start command does not start mysql.